# Using Perl to count the number of scientific numbers in a file

Tags: perl

How I can count the number of scientific numbers in a file? The file also has a few lines of header which needs to be skipped.

A portion of the file's content is in below.

```
FileHeaderLine1
FileHeaderLine2
FileHeaderLine3
FileHeaderLine4
2.91999996E-001 2.97030300E-001 3.02060604E-001 3.07090908E-001 3.12121212E-001 3.17151517E-001
3.22181821E-001 3.27212125E-001 3.32242429E-001 3.37272733E-001 3.42303038E-001 3.47333342E-001
3.52363646E-001 3.57393950E-001 3.62424254E-001 3.67454559E-001 3.72484863E-001 3.77515137E-001
3.82545441E-001 3.87575746E-001 3.92606050E-001 3.97636354E-001 4.02666658E-001 4.07696962E-001
4.12727267E-001 4.17757571E-001 4.22787875E-001 4.27818179E-001 4.32848483E-001 4.37878788E-001
4.42909092E-001 4.47939396E-001 4.52969700E-001
```

So, how can I skip the first four lines of the example above and count the number of scientific numbers in the file?

Answer (score 14):

With core module `Scalar::Util`, you can do:

```
$ perl -MScalar::Util=looks_like_number -anle '
    $count += grep { looks_like_number($_) } @F;
    END { print $count }
' file
33
```

More about `looks_like_number` can see in `perldoc perlapi`.

Comment: +1 cool, I didn't know about `looks_like_number`

Answer (score 7):

#### Using GNU grep

You can use `grep` to do this, using the PCRE facilities. Incidentally the same pattern can be used in Perl too:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+E[-+]?\d+' file.txt  | wc -l
33
```

You can also use `wc -w` to count words, I'm counting lines above, but the `grep` returns a single match on a line so it doesn't really matter in that scenario.

#### Using Perl

For Perl you could use this one liner:

```
$ perl -lane '$c += grep /\d+E[-+]?\d+/, @F; END { print $c; }' file.txt 
33
```

#### References

- [BAG OF TRICKS: A COLLECTION OF NIFTY PERL ONE LINER SCRIPTS!](http://www.chandrashekar.info/vault/perl-one-liner-scripts.html)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for the edit. Sorry I only ever am on GNU systems so do tend to forget this point all the time. I'll try to not make that mistake.

Answer (score 4):

`egrep` will work:

```
egrep "[0-9].[0-9]E-[0-9]" YourFile | wc -w
```

UPDATE:

if a line happened to contain both a number and some other string, we can use `awk` to solve the problem:

```
awk -F' ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!(i%1))$i=$i "\n"}1' YourFile | egrep "[0-9].[0-9]E-[0-9]" | wc -w ( or wc -l )
```

Comment: This would give incorrect results if a line happened to contain both a number and some other string. The answer above that uses grep's -o option to output only matches is more correct.

Comment: I didn't know about `-oP` option mentioned in slm answer before, but I have fixed my problem using `awk` @Johnny

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have only scientific numbers after 4th line, you can do something like below.

```
tail -n +5 filename | wc - w
```

For the input you have provided, the output is **33** after running the above command.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to simply count the number of *whitespace delimited fields* following the header lines in perl, I think you could just do

```
perl -lane '$sum += $#F+1 if $. > 4; END{print $sum}' file
```

If you really need to count only scientifically-formatted numbers then one approach might be to search and replace numbers according to [a suitable regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658662) and then count the number of replacements (the perl substitution expression returns the number of replacements when you bind it to a variable)

```
perl -lane '$sum += s/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?//g if $. > 4; END{print $sum}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

It all goes down to what you actually want to consider a *scientific number*, what you can expect your input to contain, and where you may accept to find those numbers in the input.

For instance, in:

```
That's inferior to the LK2E2000 model.
```

I can find either 0 or 2 (inf and 2E2000) or 3 (inf, 2E200, 0) numbers (or taken to the extreme, looking for all the sequences of characters that form a valid number: 17 (inf, 2, 2E2, 2E20, 2E200, 2E200, 2E2000, 2, 20, 200, 2000, 0, 00, 000, 0, 00, 0)).

If you know your input has only numbers in the X.XXXXXXXXE-XXX, and that they're on words of their own, it may be safer to look just for that in whole words like:

```
tr -s '[[:blank:]]' '[\n*]' | LC_ALL=C grep -xEc '[0-9]\.[0-9]{8}E-[0-9]{3}'
```

The idea there, is to get one word per line and to match the whole line (`-x`) against the pattern you want. To allow any scientify notation number (-1.2e+1234... as long as there's a `e` or `E`), you could change the pattern to:

```
[-+]?([0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.[0-9])[eE][-+]?[0-9]+
```

Or make the `e...` part optional to allow all sorts of decimal floating point numbers:

```
[-+]?([0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.[0-9])([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

That all gives the same answer for your specific input, but where that would make a difference is where there is input that departs from the strict pattern shown in your sample.